# Program executing and stops for no reason

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

so I made a poker game for my assignment.
It all works fine (at least I believe so). To make it simple : The player has a 100$ balance and based on his hand, wins or loses money.
  I made a condition that the game keeps giving the player a new hand as long as his balance is higher than <0> .
 However, after 7 or 8 restarts, the program just shows white and it keeps running forever no matter what you type in ...

Here is the code hoping you guys can help, also, sorry if most of the code is in French, I commented the methods in English to help you understand :

```
package pkgtp2;

import java.util.*;

public class TP2 {

static boolean straight;
static boolean flush;
static int paires;
static int gains;
static int balance = 100;
static char[] cardsSymbols = new char[5];
static String[] cardsValues = new String[5];
static int hand[] = new int[5];
static boolean pack[] = new boolean[52];

public static void menu(int gains) {
    System.out.println("**************            " + " AUCUNE COMBINAISON = -10$");
    System.out.println("*Jeu de Poker*            " + " 1 PAIRE = 0$");
    System.out.println("**************            " + " 2 PAIRES = 20$");
    System.out.println("                          " + " BRELAN <3> = 35$");
    System.out.println("                          " + " SUITE = 50$");
    System.out.println("                          " + " FULL = 75$");
    System.out.println("                          " + " COULEUR = 100$");
    System.out.println("                          " + " CARRÉ = 150$");
    System.out.println("                          " + " STRAIGHT FLUSH = 500$");
} // The Game Menu showing every possible hand

public static void drawCards(int[] hand, boolean[] pack) {

    Random give = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
        do {
            hand[i] = give.nextInt(52);
        } while (pack[hand[i]]);
        pack[hand[i]] = true;
    }
} // Gives the user 5 unique random numbers

public static void cardSymbol(int[] cards, char[] cardssymbols) {
    char symboles[] = {'♥', '♦', '♣', '♠'};
    int numOfSymbol;
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        numOfSymbol = cards[i] / 13;
        cardsSymbols[i] = symboles[numOfSymbol];
    }

} // Converts the 5 numbers into values

public static void cardValue(int[] cards, String[] cardsvalues) {
    String valeurs[] = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"};
    int numOfValues;
    for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        numOfValues = cards[i] % 13;
        cardsValues[i] = valeurs[numOfValues];
    }
} // Converts the 5 numbers into actual cards values

public static void printCards(char[] cardsymbols, String[] cardsvalues) {
    System.out.println("Voici vos cartes : \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(cardsymbols[i]);
        System.out.print(cardsvalues[i] + "   ");
    }
} // Prints the Cards

public static void changeCards(int[] cards, boolean[] pack) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cardchange = 0;
    Random give = new Random();
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        do {
            System.out.println(" Entrez des chiffres de 1 à 5 correspondant aux cartes que vous désirez changer (vous pouvez changer au plus 4 cartes)"
                    + " \n Si vous voulez conserver vos cartes, entrez 0 ");
            while (!read.hasNextInt()) {
                System.out.println("Veuillez entrer un chiffre ");
                read.next();
            }
            cardchange = read.nextInt();
        } while (cardchange < 0 || cardchange > 5);

        if (cardchange == 0) {
            i = 5;
        } else {
            System.out.print("\nLa carte  " + cardchange + " va être changée\n ");
            do {
                cards[cardchange - 1] = give.nextInt(52);
            } while (pack[cards[cardchange - 1]]);
            pack[cards[cardchange - 1]] = true;
        }

        cardSymbol(cards, cardsSymbols);
        cardValue(cards, cardsValues);
        printCards(cardsSymbols, cardsValues);

    }

} // Lets the user change up to 4 cards, press 0 to not change any card and skip

public static int checkPairs(char[] cardsSymbols, String[] cardsvalues) {
    int paires = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cardsvalues.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < cardsvalues.length; j++) {
            if (cardsvalues[i].equals(cardsvalues[j])) {
                paires++;
            }
        }
    }
    return paires;
} // Checks if the cards values match so the program can determine if the user has a pair, two pair, three of a kind, full house or quads

public static boolean checkFlush(char[] cardsSymbols) {
    boolean flush = false;
    if (cardsSymbols[0] == cardsSymbols[1] && cardsSymbols[1] == cardsSymbols[2] && cardsSymbols[2] == cardsSymbols[3] && cardsSymbols[3] == cardsSymbols[4]) {
        flush = true;
    }
    return flush;
} // checks for a flush

public static boolean checkStraight(String[] cardsvalues) {
    boolean straight = false;
    int numOfValues;
    int[] straightTab = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++) {
        numOfValues = hand[i] % 13;
        straightTab[i] = numOfValues;
    }
    Arrays.sort(straightTab);

    if (straightTab[0] + 1 == straightTab[1] && straightTab[1] + 1 == straightTab[2] && straightTab[2] + 1 == straightTab[3] && straightTab[3] + 1 == straightTab[4]) {
        straight = true;
    }
    return straight;
} // checks for a straight

public static int combinaisons(int paires, boolean straight, boolean flush) {
    int gains;
    if (straight && flush) {
        System.out.println("Vous avez une Quinte !");
        gains = 500;
    } else if (flush) {
        System.out.println("Vous avez une Couleur !");
        gains = 100;
    } else if (straight) {
        System.out.println("Vous avez une Suite !");
        gains = 50;
    } else if (paires == 6) {
        System.out.println("Vous avez un Carré !");
        gains = 150;
    } else if (paires == 4) {
        System.out.println("Vous avez un Full !");
        gains = 75;
    } else if (paires == 3) {
        System.out.println("Vous avez un Brelan !");
        gains = 35;
    } else if (paires == 2) {
        System.out.println("Vous avez Deux Paires !");
        gains = 20;
    } else if (paires == 1) {
        System.out.println("Vous avez une Paire !");
        gains = 0;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Vous n'avez Aucune Combinaison !");
        gains = -10;
    }
    return gains;
} // gives the user money based on his hand strength

public static int profit(int gains) {
    balance = balance + gains;
    System.out.println("Vos gains sont  de " + gains + " $");
    System.out.println("Vous avez donc " + balance + " $");
    return gains;
} // Gives the user his profit and his new balance

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    do {
        menu(gains);
        drawCards(hand, pack);
        cardSymbol(hand, cardsSymbols);
        cardValue(hand, cardsValues);
        printCards(cardsSymbols, cardsValues);
        changeCards(hand, pack);
        paires = checkPairs(cardsSymbols, cardsValues);
        flush = checkFlush(cardsSymbols);
        straight = checkStraight(cardsValues);
        gains = combinaisons(paires, straight, flush);
        profit(gains);
    }while (balance > 0);
    }// Here is my problem, the program just stops for a reason ...

}
```

Comment: May I assume that you don't have any console errors ... ?

Comment: I don't belive I have any, you can just copy/paste the code real quick and try it out for yourself

Comment: Sorry, man. I totally missed that this was Java **not** Javascript. My bad.

Comment: Is that a trailing bracket at the end?

Comment: It compiles fine as it is right now. I just tried it and it stops after 9 or so restarts as OP mentions.

Comment: Change `pack[hand[i]] = true;` to `pack[hand[i]] = false;`?

Answer (score 3):

In `drawCards` method, `pack[hand[i] = true` eventually (after 10 or so hands) sets all `pack[hand[i]` to `true`, causing `while (pack[hand[i]]);` to go into an infinite loop.

<strike>Changing `pack[hand[i]] = true;` to `pack[hand[i]] = false;` prevents the infinite loop and allows for continued game play.</strike>

One approach, as suggested by OP in comments, is to reset the "pack" array after each round, which can be done with a method:

```
public static void reset_pack(){
    for(int i=0; i<pack.length;i++){
        pack[i] = false;
    }
}
```

and call this method after each round:

```
...
profit(gains);
reset_pack();
```

Comment: Thanks , that would work but it will make my code bug as the same card could be generated twice ... any idea on how to make the "pack" array reset after each round ?

Comment: Oh good point! Thanks for pointing that out as I didn't test my logic, and indeed resetting the "pack" array would be a better approach. Perhaps a method to reset the "pack" array would work. I'll edit my answer and add code to reset the array.

Comment: Never mind ! I solved the problem thank you for your help !

Comment: Great, glad to hear you fixed it yourself ;-) Santé!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to downshift for pointing out that it would make an infinite loop.
Here is what I needed to add :

```
for (int i=0;i<hand.length;i++){
pack[hand[i]] = false;
}
```

Adding that condition after the "changeCards" method lets the program reset the "pack" array that you wont need anymore for the rest of the round. That means the program can pick the values again for the next round and therefore will not stop after 8 or 9 attempts !
Thanks